# What does this statement relative to neural network weight initialization mean?

Tags: neural-network

"The same value in all the parameters makes all the
neurons have the same effect on the input, which causes
the gradient with respect to all the weights is the same and, therefore,
the parameters always change in the same way."

Taken from my course.

Comment: If the weights of the network are initialized to the same value they will all change in the same way when doing the backpropagation (because the gradient is the same). As a result of this the model isn't able to learn, therefore it is important to initialize the weights to random values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following image of a simple neural network. Note that the network uses a linear activation function and that there are no bias terms (this makes the intuition easier).

[image]

Each path from the input to the output is as follows
$$ f(x) = (x*w1)*w4 = (x*0.5)*0.5 $$
$$ f(x) = (x*w2)*w5 = (x*0.5)*0.5 $$
$$ f(x) = (x*w3)*w6 = (x*0.5)*0.5 $$

When you perform gradient descent, the change in the weights will always be the same as each path is identical.

Comment: Is there a source for the figure, or is it yours? Thanks!

Comment: But that is irrelevant for multi-input, isn't it?

Comment: I put the image together using Canva! And for multi-input the statement in the question would be false assuming that all the inputs are different.

Answer (score 0):

If all the weights contribute equally, there is no way to single out some specific weights to penalise during backpropagation. Therefore the change in  weights is just a trivial global rescaling.